# Calling multiple functions with names matching Regex

Tags: javascript

I have some functions like these:

- `function name_a(){}`
- `function name_b(){}`
- `function name_x(){}`
- `function name_n(){}`

I want to call all functions start with **`name_`** with regex in javascript.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Curious. Are all of them global?

Comment: For global scope `Object.keys(window).filter(key => typeof window[key] === 'function' && /^name_.*/.test(key)).forEach(funcName => window[funcName]())` But I'm quite sure this approach to **original problem** is wrong.

Comment: Why don't you just make an array of functions? Then you can call `name[i]()`.

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve? This seems like a convoluted, brittle way to do most anything.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Only use case I can come up with is dealing with an incoming list of arbitrary yet consistently named commands like `/^list/` or `/^prepare/`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the kicks, here's something you can use. ES5, so IE>9 is required (could be tweaked for older browsers support, though).

```
/**
 * Calls functions of given target object with names matching given regex.
 *
 * @param {any} targetObject
 * @param {RegExp} nameRegex
 * @param {...any} functionsArguments
 *
 * @returns {any[]} The values returned by each function called.
 */
function callFunctionsMatching(targetObject, nameRegex, functionsArguments) {
      // make arguments into array, then splice
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments
    var functionsArgs = (arguments.length === 1 ? [arguments[0]] : Array.apply(null, arguments)).splice(2);

    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(targetObject).filter(function (propertyName) {
        return typeof targetObject[propertyName] == 'function' && nameRegex.test(propertyName);
    }).map(function (functionName) {
        return targetObject[functionName].apply(targetObject, functionsArgs);
    });
}
```

## Usage (**[demo JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/pocimatixi/edit?js,console,output)**)

**Global** functions (`window` target object):

```
// setup some functions
function a1(a, b, c, d) { console.log('a1->', a, b, c, d); }
function b1(arg) { console.log('b1->', arg); }
window.c1 = console.log

// call every function ending with 1
callFunctionsMatching(window, /1$/, 'stuff', 1, 3, 4);
```

Output:

```
a1-> stuff 1 3 4
b1-> stuff
stuff 1 3 4
```

---

**Objects** functions (any object as target):

```
var person = {
  aa: function(x) { console.log('person.aa called with', x); return 'this is the return value of person.aa'; },
  aaz: function(x) { console.log('I shouldn have been printed'); }
};

var valuesReturned = callFunctionsMatching(person, /aa$/, 'some argument');

console.log('valuesReturned were', valuesReturned);
```

Output:

```
person.aa called with some argument
valuesReturned were ["this is the return value of person.aa"]
```

---

**Example** from the **question**:

```
function name_a(){ console.log('name_a called'); }
function name_b(){ console.log('name_b called'); }
function name_x(){ console.log('name_x called'); }
function name_n(){ console.log('name_n called'); }

callFunctionsMatching(window, /^name_/, 'args');
```

Output:

```
function name_a called
function name_x called
function name_n called
function name_b called
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't handle DOM objects, but if you have a plain object and simply want to search for all the functions matching a certain regex at one level, you could (optionally, showing executing each one in order):

```
function get_func_filter(obj, match) {
    var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);

    return keys.filter(function(func_name) {
        return typeof obj[func_name] === 'function'
               && match.test(func_name);
    });
}

var funcs = {
    'prop_a': 'value',
    'prop_b': 'value',
    'name_a': function(){console.log('name_a function called');},
    'name_b': function(){console.log('name_b function called');},
    'name_c': function(){console.log('name_c function called');},
    'not_name_a': function(){console.log('not_name_a function called');},
    'not_name_b': function(){console.log('not_name_b function called');},
};

// First, get the function names that match "starting with name_"
get_func_filter(funcs, /^name_/)
    // Then get each name
    .map(function(func_name) {
        // And execute it (the second)
        !funcs[func_name] || funcs[func_name]();
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5vrfpmeq/